# how to not add repeated data using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="span6">
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">User Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
<div class="controls"> 
<?php
foreach($res as $key=>$value){
foreach($value as $ind=>$username){
echo '<div class="controls users">'.form_checkbox('username[]', $username).$username.'</div>';
}
}
?> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="span6">
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Programs<span class="required">*</span></label>
<?php 
$ids = explode(',', $program_id);
foreach($programs as $value){
?>
<div class="controls programs"> 
<?php echo '<label class="radio">'.form_radio('programs', $value->id).$value->program_name.'</label>' ?>
<div class="listings <?php echo $value->id ?>"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<input type="button" name="reset" value="Reset" id="reset"/>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Ok" id="oksubmit"/>
</div>
</div>
```

I have users and programs. I want to add users to programs and I am using jquery.I have added multiple users to programs.The problem is I dont want to add user twice for same program.How to do it.I tried the following in jQuery but to no avail.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
         $('.programs div.listings').slideUp();

        $('#oksubmit').click(function(){
            var error = false;
            var temp = '';
            var selusers = $('div.users span.checked input').map(function(_,el){
                return $(el).val();
            }).get();
            var prgm = $('div.programs span.checked input').val();

            if(selusers == ''){
                alert('Select at least 1 user.');
                var error = true;
                return false;
            }
            if(prgm == ''){
                alert('Select 1 program.');
                var error = true;
                return false;
            }
            if( ! error){
                $('div.'+prgm).slideDown();
                $('div.users span.checked').each(function(){ 
                    var value=$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val();
                    if($('div.'+prgm).children().length > 0){
                        $('div.'+prgm).children().each(function(){
                            var childval = $('div.list input').val();
                            if(value == childval){alert('a');
                                alert('Error');
                                var error = true;
                                return false;
                            }else{

                                alert('n');
                            }
                        })
                        if( ! error){
                            temp += '<div class="list"><input type="text" value="'+value+'" readonly></input><a class="delete" id="'+value+'">X</a></div>';
                        }
                    }else{
                        temp += '<div class="list"><input type="text" value="'+value+'" readonly></input><a class="delete" id="'+value+'">X</a></div>';
                    }

                })
                $('div.'+prgm).append(temp);


            }
});
</script>
```

Any suggesstions/help is welcome.Thanks in advance.

My solution:

```
$('#oksubmit').click(function(){
    $('div.users span.checked').each(function(){
                        var flag = true; 
                        var value = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val();
                        var child = $('div.'+prgm).find('.list').size();
                        var temp = '<div class="list"><input type="text" name="selusers['+prgm+'][]" value="'+value+'" readonly></input><a class="delete btn-danger" id="'+value+'"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a></div>';
                        $('div.'+prgm).find('div.list').each(function(ind,val){
                            var childval = $(this).find('input').val();
                            if(value == childval){
                                flag =false;
                                alert('Cant add '+value+' twice in same program');
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if(flag){
                            $('div.'+prgm).append(temp);
                        }else{
                            //alert('b')
                        }
                    })
})
```

Comment: You can save everyone some effort (and therefore get faster responses) if you place a working example on jsfiddle. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Create and fill a JavaScript object. Users as key, whatever remains in the end does not contain duplicate.

- Say we are looping over three different users
- The user 'Jack' with an ID of '42' appears twice
- When you iterate four times over the users, fill a JavaScript object while using user IDs as key

```js
var oUsers = {};
oUsers['42'] = 'Jack';
oUsers['43'] = 'Lucy';
oUsers['44'] = 'Fennel';
oUsers['42'] = 'Jack';
```

```js
> oUsers
> Object {42: "Jack", 43: "Lucy", 44: "Fennel"}
>
```

Comment: I didn't understand.Please can you elaborate a bit.

Comment: @sammy, I updated the answer. Let me know if it is not clear enough.

Comment: @sammy, I cannot check what you did at the moment (quite hard on a phone). Also, the next time you are asking for help in here, try to remove as much useless code as possible. It makes the job easier for us ;].

Comment: @sammy, If I correctly understand what you want to do, my guess would have been to first build the object (of which I told you about) and then write the corresponding HTML elements. That way you keep separated the logic and the rendering, it is both easier to write and to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#oksubmit').click(function(){
    $('div.users span.checked').each(function(){
                        var flag = true; 
                        var value = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val();
                        var child = $('div.'+prgm).find('.list').size();
                        var temp = '<div class="list"><input type="text" name="selusers['+prgm+'][]" value="'+value+'" readonly></input><a class="delete btn-danger" id="'+value+'"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a></div>';
                        $('div.'+prgm).find('div.list').each(function(ind,val){
                            var childval = $(this).find('input').val();
                            if(value == childval){
                                flag =false;
                                alert('Cant add '+value+' twice in same program');
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if(flag){
                            $('div.'+prgm).append(temp);
                        }else{
                            //alert('b')
                        }
                    })
})
```